# How to upload files on server folder using jsp

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets, upload

I am trying to upload some images on folder which locates on my server using servlet/jsp.

Below is my code, which is working on my local machine:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
     import org.apache.commons.io.output.*;

      public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private boolean isMultipart;
   private String filePath;
  private int maxFileSize = 1000 * 1024;
   private int maxMemSize = 1000 * 1024;
   private File file ;

    public void init( ){
  // Get the file location where it would be stored.
  filePath = 
         getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload"); 
   }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
           HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
  // Check that we have a file upload request
     isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
     response.setContentType("text/html");
     java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
      if( !isMultipart ){
     out.println("<html>");
     out.println("<head>");
     out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
     out.println("</head>");
     out.println("<body>");
     out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
     out.println("</body>");
     out.println("</html>");
     return;
     }
     DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
  // maximum size that will be stored in memory
     factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
  // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
     factory.setRepository(new File(" C:/Users/puneet verma/Downloads/"));  

  // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
  // maximum file size to be uploaded.
     upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

     try{ 
  // Parse the request to get file items.
     List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

  // Process the uploaded file items
      Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

     out.println("<html>");
     out.println("<head>");
     out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
     out.println("</head>");
     out.println("<body>");
     while ( i.hasNext () ) 
     {
       FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
     if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
     {
        // Get the uploaded file parameters
        String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
        String fileName = fi.getName();
        String contentType = fi.getContentType();
        boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
        long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
        // Write the file
        if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
           file = new File( filePath + 
           fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
        }else{
           file = new File( filePath + 
           fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
        }
        fi.write( file ) ;
        out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
     }
      }
     out.println("</body>");
          out.println("</html>");
     }catch(Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
     }
       }
           public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

           throw new ServletException("GET method used with " +
            getClass( ).getName( )+": POST method required.");
           } 
            }
```

Now my jsp code, where i upload file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
  <head>
      <title>File Uploading Form</title>
     </head>
       <body>
        <h3>File Upload:</h3>
      Select a file to upload: <br />
       <form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
       <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
       </form>
      </body>
        </html>
```

In My web.xml file, I've included path like this:

```
      <context-param>
<description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
<param-name>file-upload</param-name>
<param-value>
    C:\Users\puneet verma\Downloads\
 </param-value>
     </context-param>
```

I've used my server path http://grand-shopping.com/<"some folder"> , but it's not working here at all.

Libraries i'm using are:

1. commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
2. commons-io-2.2.jar

Can anyone suggest me , how exactly i need to define my server path, in order to upload images successfully.

Comment: A great answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet?rq=1

Answer (score 18):

**Below code is working on my live server as well as in my own Lapy.**

**Note:**

Please Create **data** folder in WebContent and put in any single image or any file(jsp or html file).

**Add jar files**

commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar

**upload.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
       pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="UploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select file to upload:
<input type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileChooser"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**UploadServlet.java**

```
package com.servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class UploadServlet
 */
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String DATA_DIRECTORY = "data";
    private static final int MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
    private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Check that we have a file upload request
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

        if (!isMultipart) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a factory for disk-based file items
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        // Sets the size threshold beyond which files are written directly to
        // disk.
        factory.setSizeThreshold(MAX_MEMORY_SIZE);

        // Sets the directory used to temporarily store files that are larger
        // than the configured size threshold. We use temporary directory for
        // java
        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

        // constructs the folder where uploaded file will be stored
        String uploadFolder = getServletContext().getRealPath("")
                + File.separator + DATA_DIRECTORY;

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        // Set overall request size constraint
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

        try {
            // Parse the request
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = items.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    String filePath = uploadFolder + File.separator + fileName;
                    File uploadedFile = new File(filePath);
                    System.out.println(filePath);
                    // saves the file to upload directory
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                }
            }

            // displays done.jsp page after upload finished
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/done.jsp").forward(
                    request, response);

        } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }

    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UploadServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**done.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload Done</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Your file has been uploaded!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions: (1) How do I specify an absolute path for the destination folder? (2) I'd like to pass a boolean or other message to done.jsp containing something like true (upload succeeded) or false (upload failed); how would I do that?

Comment: 1 )If you are putting absolute static path to your folder then your program is not working on live server or any other server. Above program is perfect for any change the server no need to change the code.

Comment: 2) you can put Boolean variable in below "item.write(uploadedFile);" line code as true and initialize with false value. So you can set the attribute in request and pass from the request dispatcher.

Comment: @VishalShah: i am not able to transfer xml,js,css file although it is working fine for txt,pdf,jpeg

Comment: I am getting the following error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.parseRequest` The version that I am using is `commons.fileupload1.2.1.jar`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Freakyuser - It may happen for this changing the Jar files. You can use more than 1.2.2 version I hope it will be work properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FileUploadExample extends HttpServlet {
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

            if (isMultipart) {
                // Create a factory for disk-based file items
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

                // Create a new file upload handler
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

                try {
                    // Parse the request
                    List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                    Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
                        if (!item.isFormField()) {
                            String fileName = item.getName();    
                            String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                            File path = new File(root + "/uploads");
                            if (!path.exists()) {
                                boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                            }

                            File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                            System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            item.write(uploadedFile);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: i am not able to transfer xml,js,css file although it is working fine for txt,pdf,jpeg

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload like this.

```
http://grand-shopping.com/<"some folder">
```

You need a physical path exactly like in your local

```
C:/Users/puneet verma/Downloads/
```

What you can do is create some local path where your server is working. Hence you can store and retrieve the file. If you bought some domain from any websites there will be path to upload the files. You create these variable as static constant and use it based on the server you are working (Local/Website).

Answer (score 0):

You can only use absolute path
http://grand-shopping.com/<"some folder">  is not an absolute path.

Either you can use a path inside the application which is vurneable
or you can use server specific path like in

```
windows -> C:/Users/puneet verma/Downloads/
linux -> /opt/Downloads/
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the similar problem and found the solution and i have blogged about how to [upload the file using JSP](http://vanjikumaran.blogspot.com/2013/07/upload-file-using-jsp.html) , In that example i have used the absolute path. Note that if you want to route to some other URL based location you can put a ESB like [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-example-file-processing/)