# create a video file using base64 audio and video

Tags: base64, html5-video, webrtc

I have a webapp. The client uses webrtc and recorder js  to record video and audio.
The javascript sends me the base64 version of the video and audio seperatly.

How should i proceed in create a video using just the base64 data of the seperate video and audio data.

I am using java in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC); you can get recorded "Blobs" that can be submitted to the server as XHR/FormData. See an [example](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP#javascript-code).

Then you can parse the `request` and write file to disk using `System.out.println`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510656/how-to-upload-files-on-server-folder-using-jsp#answer-19842732) for how to write posted-Blob to disk.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: blob is not defined

Comment: Did you get "Blob" like this? https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC#how-to-get-blob-object

Comment: It worked. My question to you goes like does Record-RTC together is also capable of capturing audio ?? My recording is set to go to a length of about 3-4 mins

Comment: You should try "MRecordRTC" which stands for multi-recordrtc; which records both audio/video and gif. https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/MRecordRTC You'll face some sync issues though; you're suggested to try this demo: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-Nodejs

Comment: but MRecordRTC saves the data to node.js. But in my case i just want the recorded file to get saved in a local server. so is is possible to send the the files seperately (as webm and wav) and just use your mergger.sh

Comment: You can see that both wav/webm blobs are submitted to PHP server as two unique XHR/JSON/FormData requests. You can easily use it with ruby, python, or locally within any platform: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP#javascript-code

Comment: All working good. One problen i find here again is the video blob stored on the disk pops up this error "Could not determine type of stream."