# Picking up a File autoamtically for SFTP

Tags: java, servlets

I had to automate a manual work of creating file and uploading it to server via Winscp.

I have done that part and its working well and good. But I will have to host it as a web application.

When I run from local my file path is static so file gets uploaded properly.

But now Many ppl will have to use this. So they ll have to upload the file from their machine. That uplaoded file has to be stored in my machine(where i have hosted this tool-tomcat) once the file is uploaded and is palced in a path specified automatically the file should be picked up and SFTP has to be done.

How can I do this ?

PS : SFTP via java I have done. Its working fine. How to upload a file and pick it up automatically for SFTP transfer using JAVA SERVLET JSP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `WatchService` to pick up new files uploaded to your directory, as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html). The advantage to this approach, compared to some action hardwired to an upload field, is that you can also upload the files using some other method (like FTP) and have the same code handle them.

File upload is demonstrated in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510656/how-to-upload-files-on-server-folder-using-jsp).

Comment: can you give an example program for it ? it would be really helpful thanks