# How to config the web.xml tomcat in with XAMPP

Tags: tomcat

I only had experience in tomcat in XAMPP without web.xml. I need to create a upload file to server page now and it must include servlet. I follow exactly the first answer in this instruction:
[How to upload files on server folder using jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510656/how-to-upload-files-on-server-folder-using-jsp)
I create a WEB-INF folder in my webapp folder, and put the web.xml in it.
Then "The requested resource is not available." error appears when I try to access upload.jsp. The other webapps are fine without problem but they don't have their own WEB-INF and web.xml. What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using an IDE, in which case you should start now.

Comment: How do do that without IDE? This is for work and I am in hurry, I don't have time to learn a lot in so short time.

Comment: please post you `web.xml` to review

Comment: It is exactly the same as the first answer in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510656/how-to-upload-files-on-server-folder-using-jsp

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't know how to set the location for jsp pages, but even I directly run the servlet, it is still the same error.

Comment: You will have to learn less with an IDE than doing it manually. Trust me.

Comment: Should I try Eclipse then? Just run Eclipse EE version, then build the project page by page then it will automatically generates the web.xml?