# How to upload the file(.doc,jpeg,xlsx,pdf) on sever using html and java

Tags: java, html

I'm newbie to Java and I have create simple HTML form for files upload (All type of file). I want to upload the file to directly to my server.

My URL is http://www.example.com

My html code is

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form  name="data" action="" method="post">
            <div id="formName">
                <label>Pancard:</label><br />
                <input type="file" name="pancard"  id="pancard" class="required">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Details" name="Submit" >
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to upload and save the uploaded file in server (in my url) using Java at the backend.

I need to store the all upload file in server and i download the file from server directly.

I don't want to store in local or temp file. When i upload the file and save it in my server (example URL)...

How to save or upload the file direct to server(URL)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show effort and code. Not just a form. There are answers to your questions all over the net and SO

Comment: Have you searched your title on Google?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Comment: @mplugjan i try some code but i need to store upload file in my url(server)...

Comment: Yes - you need a java server process or are you confusing JAVA the server programming language with JavaScript the client scripting language? They are NOT the same.

Comment: @mplungjan i try some java servalet  sample program and upload file store in my tmp directory.http://www.journaldev.com/1964/servlet-upload-file-download-example#comment-36630  i tried this sample code and i dont know where put my url for store the uploaded image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342506/why-is-form-enctype-multipart-form-data-required-when-uploading-a-file

Answer (score 0):

For file upload, the `form` should be use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input id="fileToUpload" type="file" name="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

In your java, you should get the file and define the location to store the image. I find below two links are similar to your questions, you can try.

- [How to upload files on server folder using jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510656/how-to-upload-files-on-server-folder-using-jsp)
- http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql

Hope this help!

Comment: i don't know where i define the my server url in my code. i use the sample code from this site journaldev.com/1964/servlet-upload-file-download-example

Comment: After submit button click, you can set the form ``action`` to your java. 1. Define a controller, set a route, the form action goes to the route. Write the logic in Model, then call the model in controller.........2. Use Servlet, after submit button click, form action goes to the servlet.